# Java retry after IOException

Tags: java, inputstream, ioexception

If I have stream that I expect at times may throw an `IOException`, and want to catch the exception and retry where will the stream be (i.e. will the mark still be after the last successfully read block/byte)?  Ca I simply catch the exception and execute the same `read(byte[])` and have any expectation I will not be missing data?  Thanks.

Comment: you will have to start again and initiate new streams as far as i know

Comment: Why are you *expecting* an IOException?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `mark()`/`reset()` methods,  AOP, and Java annotations from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-retryonfailure.html) (I'm a developer). The function that reads will look like this (pseudo code):

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 5)
private byte[] read(InputStream stream, int length) {
  stream.reset();
  byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
  stream.read(bytes, 0, length);
  stream.mark(length);
  return bytes;
}
```

If an IOException is thrown at `stream.read(bytes, 0, length)` call to `mark()` won't happend and the next call to `reset()` will set the pointer to the previous position.

Answer (score 0):

Some IOExceptions are fatal where you can't expect to continue. Make sure successive retries may succeed. (Ie. check whether the exception at hand is recoverable.)

Comment: this is true for almost everything except "timeout" IOExceptions, like SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: -1 These kinds of broad, sweeping generalizations are always wrong.  I had an IOException today (ConnectException) that I did an exponential backoff/retry on, and it recovered and continued.

Comment: the OP didn't specify a particular type of IOException.  As a class, you have to treat IOExceptions as fatal.  If you have a specific subclasses, of course there can be recoverable errors.

Comment: That's why your sweeping generalization (IOExceptions are fatal) is wrong. ;)

Comment: @DonBranson You didn't reuse the same `Socket` when you did the reconnect: so that doesn't count as 'non-fatal' for the original `Socket`. A second `Socket.connect()` call after one has failed doesn't work: you get 'socket operation on non-socket', i.e. it *is* fatal. The only `IOException` on a socket you can recover from is a `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: @EJP - You're right in what you say, given your interpretation of  "IOExceptions are fatal," which is ambiguous enough to be interpreted in different ways.  I interpreted it to mean fatal to the app, not the socket.

Comment: @DonBranson 'Fatal to the app' isn't a reasonable interpretation. If you can catch it, it isn't fatal.

Comment: ddyer, could you clarify? What are possible underlying causes that could make a file-reading IOException not retryable?

Comment: This is meaningless without context. It is fine to retry requests to HTTP servers, for example.

Comment: You can create a new stream and retry the transaction, but the stream that threw the exception is dead dead dead.